# Getting a list of values from API Server

Tags: json, api, retrofit2

I am still learning about API fetching. I want to get a list of values instead of just one value.

I am currently calling this API https://www.omdbapi.com that returns a movie based off the name or id:

```
http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=nameOfMovie
```

When calling that url with something like 'batman' it returns one json value of one of the batman movies. How would I be able to fetch a list? Or would that be entirely up to the people who run the API?

Comment: that's up to the API. Looking at the docs I can't see an option to get a list of movies. When you say a list what do you mean? A list of batman movies?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald yes. Like a list of movies related to the value that was searched. Thank you for the clarifying!